# continuity of polynomial of two variables

Tags: polynomials, continuity

We know that polynomial functions are always continuous. The proof which I did was only for single variable polynomial. What about the polynomials in two variables? Can we say a polynomial of two or more variable is always  continuous?

Comment: Yes they are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials in several variables are everywhere continuous, yes. The reason is, that the sum, difference, product (and quotient) of two continuous functions is again continuous, whenever defined. So start with constant functions $f(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=c$ and perform addition and multiplication on constants and on functions $p_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$,

Comment: what about this example: $f(x,y)=3xy ; (x,y)\neq (1,2)$ $f(x,y)= 6;  (x,y)=(1,2)$. This has a removable discontinuity.So all other functions of this form can have removable discontinuity.

Comment: It has no removable discontinuity.

Comment: sorry I was about to write some constant other than 6, i.e, $f(x,y) =16$ say at$ (x,y)=(1,2)$.then what will be the case?